# MS SQL Server Permissions

Tags: sql-server, database

I would like to create a custom security group in MS SQL Server that permits access to multiple databases. But it seems like you have to create a separate security role for each database, which seems a bit redundant to me.
Is there a better way to do it?
Thank you!

Comment: Did you have a question or just want to express that you don't like how security works?

Comment: I want to know if there is a better way to do it?